# Microcontrollerkit No longer compiles code after update

Tags: code-generation, code, microcontroller-kit

I recently restarted a project where I used `MicrocontrollerKit` to generate code for me into the Wiring language to be then imported into arduino IDE for editing and uploading, this has been working well since day one, however now when rerunning the old code (and what appears to be a paclet update, I now get only errors and a window that flashes complaining about something then dissappears before I can read it....

The final error being :

```
MicrocontrollerKit`MicrocontrollerEmbedCode::The sampling period 
MicrocontrollerKit`Atmel8Dump`sp is expected to be a positive value for real-time code generation.
```

The sampling of my code is most certainly positive, and again this was working code only some weeks ago.

Example code:

```
NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, {-{1, 2, 3, 4}.{\[Theta][t] - \[Pi], \[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t], d}}}, {}, {\[Theta][t], \[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t], d}]

dd = 150 10^(-6); 
ssmd = ToDiscreteTimeModel[ssm, dd]
mm = MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[ssmd, <|"Target" -> "ArduinoUno", "Inputs" -> {"A0" -> "Analog", "A1" -> "Analog", "A2" -> "Analog"}, "Outputs" -> {"Serial"}|>, <|"ConnectionPort" -> None|>, <|"Language" -> "Wiring"|>]
mm["SourceCode"]
```

Has something changed in how MicrocontrollerKit translates?

I have gone through documentation and haven't been able to find any recent changes in examples that I used before to generate the code to begin with.

Comment: It works fine for me. What is the result of `PacletObject["MicrocontrollerKit"]["Version"]`? Could it be some transient glitch? Can you Quit and try again.

Comment: It appears I don't have `PacletObject` as a command? Restarting MMA and running just Needs["MicrocontrollerKit`] gives me EmbeddedSystemsTools::dlfail: Internet download of data for EmbeddedSystemsTools failed. Use Help > Internet Connectivity... to test or reconfigure internet connectivity. as an error...but clearly I have internet.

Comment: I am running v12, i should mention.

Comment: It looks like the issue is in the internal EmbeddedSystemsTools paclet? What is the result of ``"Version" /. PacletManager`PacletInformation /@ {"MicrocontrollerKit", "EmbeddedSystemsTools"}``? Can you try ``PacletManager`PacletInstall["EmbeddedSystemsTools"]`` if you don't have it.

Comment: PacletInstall::notavail: No paclet named EmbeddedSystemsTools is available for download from any currently enabled paclet sites.

is the error I get, and {"1.1.1", "Version"} the result of your code

Comment: So that paclet is missing. I will get that resolved soon and let you know.

Comment: The paclet will be on the server on Monday. I will let you know then. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: This is now fixed. In a fresh kernel, evaluate ``Needs["MicrocontrollerKit`"]`` and make sure that there is internet connection. It should download the missing paclet.

Comment: @SubaThomas Back to normal, thanks for the help!